# Q# installation on Heroku

Tags: programming, q#

I'm trying to deploy a simple Quantum App written using Python on Heroku Server which is also using Microsoft's Q#, but getting the below error:

```
AttributeError: module 'qsharp' has no attribute 'clients'
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/qrng_final.py", line 18, in <module>
    import qsharp
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qsharp/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    client = _start_client()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qsharp/clients/__init__.py", line 31, in _start_client
    client = qsharp.clients.iqsharp.IQSharpClient()
```

Log from the docker image:

```
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: /appjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:/app$ ls
Dockerfile  Operation.qs  README.md  qrng_final.py     runtime.txt
LICENSE     Procfile      obj        requirements.txt  setup.sh
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: /appjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:/app$ ls $HOME/.local/bin
base58     f2py3         pip3             pybind11-config  virtualenv
cygdb      f2py3.7       pip3.7           sample           virtualenv-clone
cython     get_objgraph  pipenv           streamlit        watchmedo
cythonize  isympy        pipenv-resolver  streamlit.cmd
f2py       pip           plasma_store     undill
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: /appjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:/app$ ls $HOME/.local/binls $HOME/.local/bin $HOME/.local/bin $HOME/.local/binc $HOME/.local/bind $HOME/.local/bin $HOME/.local/bin$HOME/.local/bin
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.local/binjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local/bin$ ls streamlit
streamlit
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.local/binjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local/bin$ ls streamlit/streamltit
ls: cannot access 'streamlit/streamlit': Not a directory
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.local/binjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local/bin$ ls streamlit/streamlit streamlit/streamlit streamlit/streamlitc streamlit/streamlita streamlit/streamlitt streamlit/streamlit
cat: streamlit/streamlit: Not a directory
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.local/binjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local/bin$ cat steeamlit
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from streamlit.cli import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(main())
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.local/binjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local/bin$ cd ..
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: ~/.localjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:~/.local$ vfcf f ..cd /app
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: /appjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:/app$ ls
Dockerfile  Operation.qs  README.md  qrng_final.py     runtime.txt
LICENSE     Procfile      obj        requirements.txt  setup.sh
ovyan@7ca97f8365fb: /appjovyan@7ca97f8365fb:/app$ $HOME/.local/bin/streamlit run qrng_final.py 
2021-02-06 23:56:11.279 
Warning: the config option 'server.enableCORS=false' is not compatible with 'server.enableXsrfProtection=true'.
As a result, 'server.enableCORS' is being overridden to 'true'.

More information:
In order to protect against CSRF attacks, we send a cookie with each request.
To do so, we must specify allowable origins, which places a restriction on
cross-origin resource sharing.

If cross origin resource sharing is required, please disable server.enableXsrfProtection.
            
2021-02-06 23:56:13.041 
Warning: the config option 'server.enableCORS=false' is not compatible with 'server.enableXsrfProtection=true'.
As a result, 'server.enableCORS' is being overridden to 'true'.

More information:
In order to protect against CSRF attacks, we send a cookie with each request.
To do so, we must specify allowable origins, which places a restriction on
cross-origin resource sharing.

If cross origin resource sharing is required, please disable server.enableXsrfProtection.
            

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://172.17.0.2:8501
  External URL: http://106.51.241.244:8501

/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:107: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  z = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:108: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  x = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:107: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  z = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:108: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  x = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:107: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  z = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:108: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  x = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:107: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  z = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:108: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  x = np.zeros(len(label), dtype=np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/pauli.py:30: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  arr = np.asarray(arr).astype(np.bool)
2021-02-06 23:56:17.792 Starting IQ# kernel...
2021-02-06 23:56:23.896 Exception while checking if IQ# is ready.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qsharp/clients/iqsharp.py", line 97, in is_ready
    result = self.component_versions(timeout=6)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qsharp/clients/iqsharp.py", line 193, in component_versions
    self._execute("%version", output_hook=capture, _quiet_=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qsharp/clients/iqsharp.py", line 270, in _execute
    reply = self.kernel_client.execute_interactive(input, output_hook=_output_hook, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/blocking/client.py", line 321, in execute_interactive
    raise TimeoutError("Timeout waiting for output")
TimeoutError: Timeout waiting for output
Preparing Q# environment...
2021-02-06 23:56:27.619 Q# version
{'iqsharp': LooseVersion ('0.15.2101126940'), 'Jupyter Core': LooseVersion ('1.5.0.0'), '.NET Runtime': LooseVersion ('.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1')}
```

I have already given Q#package name in `requirements.txt` but still not able to resolve it. Is there any solution around how can I install Q# binded with Python on any remote server?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Heroku does not currently support installing additional software, such as the IQ# kernel used by the `qsharp` Python package. That said, [Heroku's documentation suggests](https://help.heroku.com/IYRYW6VB/how-do-i-install-additional-software-packages-that-my-application-requires) that using Docker can allow for providing additional dependencies. The Quantum Development Kit is published along with a Docker image, `iqsharp-base`, that provides everything you need to use Q# and Python together within a Docker environment:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/quantum/iqsharp-base:0.15.2101125897
```

Comment: Hey Chris,
I tried Docker as well, but with this docker image I don't have access as a root user because of which not able to install other packages at the default location

Comment: The `iqsharp-base` Docker image is designed for use with tools like mybinder.org which require running as non-root users, but that can be overridden by using the `USER` command in a Dockerfile that inherits `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/quantum/iqsharp-base:0.15.2101125897`. Alternatively, you can see the code we used to build that image at https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/blob/main/images/iqsharp-base/Dockerfile.

Comment: I tried creating a Doker image using this file as well, but it's throwing some error at Line 97. Any changes you suggest in the below docker file which overrides the `jovyan` user and installs my dependencies as root user?
https://github.com/shadab-entrepreneur/Quantum-Random-Number-Generator-using-Streamlit/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: Also I have added logs from the docker image, see if you can help out

Comment: I didn't see the logs, but looking at https://github.com/shadab-entrepreneur/Quantum-Random-Number-Generator-using-Streamlit/blob/main/Dockerfile, line 10 fails as the current user set by the `FROM` line is still `jovyan`. To override and get back to `root`, you need a `USER root` command to appear above the Docker commands that you want to run as `root`.

Comment: I have added the `User root` and able to start streamlit server on Heroku, but Q# is throwing an [error](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/407).